# Bubble sort in C: Function not changing array data

Tags: c, bubble-sort

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testSort(int values[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    int hs[] = {5,3,2,1,4};
    printf("Unsorted: %i %i %i %i %i\n", hs[0], hs[1], hs[2], hs[3], hs[4]);
    testSort(hs, 5);

    printf("Sorted: %i %i %i %i %i\n", hs[0], hs[1], hs[2], hs[3], hs[4]);
}

void testSort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int hold;
        int current = values[i];
        int next = values[i + 1];

        if (current > next)
        { 
            hold = current;
            current = next;
            next = hold;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm trying to do bubble sort and right now it goes through the array once, but my question is: Why isn't my `hs[]` updating after calling function? The second `printf` shows that it remained the same.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned, turns out I *was* changing data but of the *copies*. For some reason I when I created the variables `current/next` I felt as if they were *representing* `values[i]/values[i+1]` but in reality I was just creating new variable and passing the *value* of `values[0]` which is 5 and assigning it to `current`. Obviously leaving values[] unchanged. Thanks everyone

Comment: You need to swap `values[i]` with `values[i+1]`. All the code does is swap the copies in `current` and `next`.

Comment: Your function doesn't modify `values[i]` anywhere.

Comment: @Fang You cannot pass an array by value, it decays into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: The function isn't changing the data, because it contains no code that changes the data... Surely you could figure this out yourself by spending a moment to read your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're only modifying the function's local variables, not the array's elements.

It's the same principle as why this program will print `1` and not `2`:

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1};
    int x = array[0];
    x = 2;
    printf("array[0] = %d\n", array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to assign values to the array's elements:

```
void testSort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] > values[i+1])
        { 
            int hold = values[i];
            values[i] = values[i+1];
            values[i+1] = hold;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you've fixed this, you will notice that this function only works for some inputs.
Solving that bug is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```
 void bubble_sort(int list[], int n){
      int c, d, t;
      for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
      {
         for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
          {
             if (list[d] > list[d+1])
             {
                 t         = list[d];
                 list[d]   = list[d+1];
                 list[d+1] = t;
             }
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: A little explanation might help here.

Comment: first you will try this code & check is it work or not.then I will explain it

Comment: @SarikaKoli: No, that's nonsense. You are making suggestions to change the code and therefore should explain them right away, not after someone else has verifies thetsolution is correct. (That's your job as answrer, by the way: To provide working code. Whether that is by being confident or by testing actual code doesn't matter.)